# Can a property value include inline styles?

Tags: reactjs, properties, inline-styles

Trying to create a BlogPost component that includes the props title and text. I can't implement text styling to the post text. How can the text include "", italic
, strong, anchor links or other html text styles within the attribute value string?
Or is there another way to create this component structure ad keep it easy to manage when creating the blog posts?

Example:

```
    App.js

    <article>
              <BlogPost
                title = "Definition - Software developer"
                text = "According to Wikipedia: A software developer is a person concerned with facets of the software development process, including the research, design, programming, and testing of computer software. Other job titles which are often used with similar meanings are programmer, software analyst, and software engineer. ..The single individual is also called by the name God and speaks the language of C."
              />
</article>

    BlogPost.js

    return (
    <div>
      <h2 id="postHeader"> {title} </h2>
      <p className="PostText"> {text} </p>
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

use this package [react-markdown](https://github.com/rexxars/react-markdown)

Comment: Great, that worked like a charm. The BlogPost.js takes now <ReactMarkDownBlogText input = {text}/> from ReactMarcdown component.  App.js has the constant that includes html tags: const blogpost1 and the component <BlogPost title"" text = {blogpost1}/>